# WSl and Ubuntu both terminal having issue of the cursor blinking on left top corner nothing able to type

Tags: virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I already had wsl2 installed with ubuntu in my windows system earlier it was working fine but due to some requirement I need to install Virtual box after installing I'm facing wsl and ubuntu terminal left corner cursor blinking.
Hoping someone knows the solution thanks.